# Local path strings inside library binaries

Tags: gcc, mingw, build-process, configure

After using MinGW+MSYS to build various libraries, I noticed that all resulting binaries (.a, .dll, .exe files) contain the local paths of the build directory:

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\UserName\LibraryDir
```

I have tried stripping what I thought were symbols by using the below commands, but it didn't work:

```
sh ./configure LDFLAGS="-s"
make
```

Question 1: what is the purpose for saving this seemingly useless information to binaries which will be used by other people anyway?

Question 2: how can I prevent it from being saved altogether (is there a switch in GCC to turn it off)?

Answer (score 0):

As already answered on MinGW mailing list, looks like you are building with debugging information embedded. To remove that, run the strip utility on your executables, after completing the build.

```
strip *.exe *.dll
```

Don't strip your libraries like this, however, or you will make them unusable. Better to keep them as is, with debugging information in place, unless you plan to distribute them as "release-only" quality, (which I don't really recommend -- executables and DLLs are the normal release quality distributables). If you *must* do this, you need to add the "-g" flag to "strip":

```
strip -g *.a
```